# Subtracting value from the result of a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, shopping-cart

I'm using the module 'ngCart' to act as a shopping cart for a website and I am trying to set up an additional way to implement a voucher system my app.

so far, my method looks like this:

```
    ngCart.applyFiveVoucher = function(){
        if(ngCart.setFiveVoucher) {
            this.totalCost() -= 5
        }
```

but is returning:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I understand that you cannot alter the return of a function but I am unable to edit the method within the module as these changes will not be passed on if other people try and use my repo.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "as these changes will not be passed on if other people try and use my repo"? You need to add a new method `subtractFromTotalCost(5)`, it's new functionality, users would have to get a later version of your module

Comment: If someone else downloaded my repo and ran npm install, they would get the original version of ngCart, and not my updated version... So somehow I need to edit the methods from my controller or try a completely new approach

Answer (score -1):

You cannot assign to a function result.

ngCart.applyFiveVoucher = function(){ if(ngCart.setFiveVoucher) { return this.totalCost() - 5; }

Comment: Not without modifying the original source, passing by reference.

Comment: @chongo2002 Passing by reference? in JavaScript.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention, was thinking c#. Does the total cost function have a variable you can access and modify? Post the code please.